# How to save meta checkbox WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to save a meta with a checkbox for all my posts, here's my code :

```
add_action( 'save_post','save_metaboxes' );

function save_metaboxes( $post_ID ) {

    if( isset( $_POST['is_viewpay'] ) ) {

        if( !empty( $_POST['is_viewpay'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_is_viewpay', 'active' );
        } else {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_is_viewpay', '' );
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is when I uncheck the checkbox and save my post, It always stay checked. I don't know why.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you sure that 'active' is the value that needs to be set? is it not 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uncheck the checkbox, `isset($_POST['is_viewpay'])` will evaluate to `false` so it skips over your remaining code.

Instead you could do:

```
if(isset($_POST['is_viewpay'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_is_viewpay', 'active');
} else {
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_is_viewpay', '');
}
```

As a side note, it's highly recommended to use [Nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) (which will help protect your page from malicious attacks).